# Linking videos to posts with node.js and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, video, streaming

TL;DR - What method is used to link a file upload to a blog/social media post in mongoDB?

I am working on creating a video streaming app, however whilst I can successfully upload large videos with gridfs, I am unsure how to link them to the post I am posting them in.

Briefly, I am creating a social media type app, so I am simply trying to accomplish posting videos to stream on the feed. My problem is both the post and video upload succesfully, but when I GET the post there is no video linked to it?

Here is my code for storing and posting the videos;

```
import PostModel from "../../database/models/Post.js";
import User from "../../database/models/User.js";
import { Router } from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import multer from "multer";
import crypto from "crypto";
import { GridFsStorage } from "multer-gridfs-storage";
import Grid from "gridfs-stream";
import { JWTAuthMiddleware } from "../../auth/token.js";
import path from "path";
import mongo from "mongodb";
import "dotenv/config";

const postRouter = Router();

const mongoURI = process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION;

const db = mongoURI;
const gfs = await Grid(db, mongo);

// Create storage engine

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads",
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// Create Post

postRouter.post(
  "/",
  JWTAuthMiddleware,
  upload.single("video"),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const newPost = new PostModel(req.body);
    try {
      const savedPost = await newPost.save();
      const payload = new FormData();
      const video = req.video;
      payload.append("video", video);
      console.log({ video: req.video });
      res.status(200).json(savedPost);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json(error);
    }
  }
);
```

When I fetch a post I am getting this in Postman

[image: When I fetch a post I am getting this in Postman]

Post example

[image: Post example]

MongoDB example

[image: MongoDB example]

I hope this is enough info, if need anything else please let me know, thanks for any help!

Comment: Store the gridfs id in the post document, like you did with the `userId`? Or is that too simple?

Comment: "Or is that too simple?" .... nicely worded. I am a beginner, so nothing is. For that I believe I'd need to create a schema for the videos that has the user id within, I just need to figure out posting with 2 schemas so both are applied not just the PostModel